# how to compare 2 audio files in different formats(e.g. MP3 & WAV)

Tags: c#

I want to compare two audio files that are the **same songs** but they are not in the same format(e.g. one is MP3 and the second is WAV) . so,I gess I will get a different hash code for each one ,
is there any way to recognize that they are the same songs??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if their contents are exactly same then you can get same Hash (like MD5 Hash) and do the comparison. But if their contents are even little bit different like same song but one with more dead space in the beginning or end of song then Hash will be different. Then the other thing you can do is to probably start reading the data and recognize them using some library and compare the waveform maybe.

Comment: thanks, I tryed to get MD5 hash for the 2 files and I got different code for each one, I assume because they are in different formats. if you can please direct me how can I read the data that is needed for recognizing it.thanks a lot!